# are the m74hc595bl and 74hct93 interchangeable?

Tags: shift-register, rgb, 74hc595

Im about to put an RGB fader circuit together and it requires the 74hct93. I have quite a few of the 74hc595's. I thought since they are close in name and both shift registers I would ask.

74hc595
http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/243947/STMICROELECTRONICS/M74HC595B1R/1948/1/M74HC595B1R.html

74hct93
http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/15674/PHILIPS/74HCT93/497/2/74HCT93.html

Comment: We will need links to datasheets.  Also, in the title of your Q you said 74hct793, but later you said 74hct93.  Which is it?

Comment: Seriously? By this logic, there should only be one IC ever.

Comment: NOt really a helpful comment Connor Wolf. Stop by often to make new users feel like dicks? You could have just not posted. Maybe choose that option in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not interchangeable.  Not even close.  The '93 isn't a shift register.